# Sending SMS through gateway not working

Tags: php, gateway

I am trying to send the messages through "email to sms" gateway for that i have the following code:

```
<?php
require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '<my-email>@gmail.com';          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '<password>'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('<my-email>@gmail.com', 'abhishek');
$mail->addAddress('<mob-no>@bplmobile.com');   // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

$bodyContent = 'Hello world';
$mail->Subject = 'Demo Subject';
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

I have got the gateway from [here](https://www.opentextingonline.com/emailtotext.aspx). 
I have tried all the gateways in the link, but the message doesn't seems to be deliver.

Comment: Have you tried sending an email manually to check whether the email to sms gateway works or not?

Comment: i would never use carrier email to sms gateways they are notoriously unreliable

Comment: not tried manually yet :/ @PrateekGupta

Comment: You can use `twilio`, it has a nice SMS API and also it has high coverage around the world. SMS gateways are unreliable as @nogad said. Also, try it manually once, if it works then try fixing the code.

Comment: manually doesn't works. The gateways seems to be changed :/ @PrateekGupta . Going with `twilio` is the only option left. :P

Comment: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=sms+gateway quite a few options

Comment: @abhishekbagul I have used `twilio` extensively for many applications, its reliability is highest among such providers.

PS: I am in no way associated to twilio, just a user with good experience.

Answer (score 1):

Email to SMS gateways are a thing of past. Today none of the providers provide email address based on number. Best solution is to use a sms gateway like [`twilio`](http://twilio.com/).